# Calculate the age using the date of birth

Tags: java, android, date

I am developing an android app to find the age from the date of birth provided by user.. three edit-texts are there one for day and other two for month and year. I got the code from this [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/calculate-age).. But I dont know what to do next... I am giving the code so far I created... pls check and help me...

**main_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:onClick="getAge"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    long a =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        Button btn1  = (Button)   findViewById (R.id.button1)  ;
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

    }


    public int getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;         

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
        a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                --a;
        }
        if(a < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
        return a;
}

}
```

Comment: My advice. Don't just pick up the code written by someone else as such. Make an attempt yourself and look for help on the internet on specific technical problems alone.

Comment: what does "I do not know what to do next" mean?

Comment: That code seems fairly wasteful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should add a click listener to your button, then in it, calculate the age and display it in your TextView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    long a =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        final EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        Button btn1  = (Button)   findViewById (R.id.button1)  ;
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                int day = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                int month = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
                int year = Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString());

                tv1.setText(String.valueOf(MainActivity.this.getAge(year, month, day)));
            }
        });
    }


    public int getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;         

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
        a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                --a;
        }
        if(a < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: " The method parseInt(string) in the type integer is not applicable for the arguments (editable) " Error msg is showing like this....

Comment: These date-time classes are legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Period.between( 
    LocalDate.of( Integer.parseInt( … ) , … , … ) ,  // ( year, month, dayOfMonth )
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) 
).getYears()
```

## Details

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Unlike the legacy classes, the months have sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( Integer.parseInt( … ) , … , … ) ;  // year , month , day
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Representing a span of time in granularity of days-months-years is done with the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period age = Period.between( localDate , today );
```

To get a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `age.toString()`. Or interrogate for each part, years, months, days.

```
int y = age.getYears();
int m = age.getMonths();
int d = age.getDays();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

In button click just pass the values from edit text boxes to the method and display the return value in textview...

Answer (score 0):

First create a class:

public class AgeCalculation {

```
private int startYear;
private int startMonth;
private int startDay;
private int endYear;
private int endMonth;
private int endDay;
private int resYear;
private int resMonth;
private int resDay;
private Calendar start;
private Calendar end;

public String getCurrentDate() {
    end = Calendar.getInstance();
    endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    endMonth = end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    endMonth++;
    endDay = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return endDay + ":" + endMonth + ":" + endYear;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
    startYear = sYear;
    startMonth = sMonth;
    startDay = sDay;

}

public int calcualteYear() {
    resYear = endYear - startYear;

    if (endMonth < startMonth){

        resYear --;

    }


    return resYear;

}

public int calcualteMonth() {
    if (endMonth >= startMonth) {
        resMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
    } else {
        resMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
        resMonth = 12 + resMonth;
        resYear--;
    }

    return resMonth;
}

public int calcualteDay() {

    if (endDay >= startDay) {
        resDay = endDay - startDay;
    } else {
        resDay = endDay - startDay;
        resDay = 30 + resDay;
        if (resMonth == 0) {
            resMonth = 11;
            resYear--;
        } else {
            resMonth--;
        }

    }

    return resDay;
}

public String getResult() {
    return resDay + ":" + resMonth + ":" + resYear;
}


public String dob (int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
    startYear = sYear;
    startMonth = sMonth;
    startDay = sDay;

    return  startDay + "/" + startMonth + "/" + startYear;

}
```

}

then simply call these method in your activity

```
AgeCalculation age = new AgeCalculation ();
  age.getCurrentDate();
  age.setDateOfBirth(getYear, getMonth, getDate);
  int calculatedYear =  age.calcualteYear();
  int calculatedMonth = age.calcualteMonth();
  int calculatedDate = age.calcualteDay();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.